# Change a users Maximo password from a Worklight developed mobile app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, maximo, maximo-anywhere

We have developed our own mobile application using IBM Worklight, which interfaces with Maximo. Currently, all users have to have a Maximo account that is setup with a default password when created. When the mobile user logs in to the app, their credentials are verified with Maximo and access is granted / denied as appropriate.

What I want to do is force the user to change their password (from the mobile app) when they first login and then every (x) number of days thereafter.

1. Does anyone know if there is an existing service / method that can be invoked to do this? (which would be my preferred method).
2. I know that the users password is stored in the database as an encrypted string and, if it was possible to replicate the same encryption method, I could just overwrite the existing string with the new one. But, what is the encryption method used and how has it been implemented?

Any advice / info is most welcome.

Many thanks, Chris.

Comment: 1. Requiring users to change their password every (x) days is a horrible method that will lead to really bad passwords, users give up on creating good passwords when the effort to come up with them and memorize them is invalidated often. 2. Do not store encrypted passwords, that is what attackers want, so when they get the DB and encryption key they will have all the passwords. Instead you need to save passwords that have been mac'ed with a random salt and iterated for up to 100ms. Use a method such as PBKDF2, bcrypt, password_hash, script or similar function.

Comment: Here are some links to best practices: See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

Comment: Hi zaph - Thanks for the info. I should have pointed out that this is an Enterprise app for internal employee use only, and is only available from a private app store. As such, it has to comply with the corporate password policy, hence the need to force password changes. Otherwise I would implement something else for exactly the reasons you have pointed out above. The main encryption routines (which have to match Maximo, unless I can call the Maximo routines somehow?) will be implemented on the server side. This keeps them well away from the users and behind several layers of security...

Comment: Ah, I understand, the concept is that an attacker would never want that information because it is enterprise only. Attackers are not allowed to access enterprise only data. never happens.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. The app is secure end to end (at least as secure as it can be) and we get everything pen tested by a 3rd party to make sure. What I need to do is enforce that passwords are changed according to corporate policy (that's the easy bit). However, I need to either call the Maximo password encryption method, or replicate it myself, on the server side (which is the bit I'm currently missing).

Comment: See [Microsoft’s Password Recommendations](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/05/30/microsofts-password-recommendations/): *Password expiry

Microsoft notes that research has shown that users tend to pick predictable passwords when passwords expire, usually based on the previous password.

There is evidence to suggest that users who are required to change their passwords **frequently select weaker passwords** to begin with and then change them in predictable ways that attackers can guess easily.*

Comment: The problem we are seeing in security is a bunch of IT folks who are just not keeping up with best practices. Professionals are usually required to obtain at least 40 hours of approved continuing education per year. Does IT require that? If not they are not professionals. My wife must submit here continuing education hours along with supporting information on the education received and they must be approved be the certifying organization or she loose her certification.

Comment: zaph - I get your point and I agree wholeheartedly with you, but, I don't make the rules, my employer does and I have to follow them. That's all there is to it...

Comment: You do realize you are complicit in the practice, right? Really, how will we get good security if we just roll over to bad practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there is an existing service / method that can be invoked to do this? (which would be my preferred method).

There is nothing in Worklight/MobileFirst to do this for you. If this is what you want to do, you need to write your own custom logic (custom authenticator): https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/custom-authentication/

> I know that the users password is stored in the database as an encrypted string and, if it was possible to replicate the same encryption method, I could just overwrite the existing string with the new one. But, what is the encryption method used and how has it been implemented?

It is unclear to which encryption method you are talking about. Worklight/MobileFirst by default does encrypt anything in the database, so it sounds like this is custom Maximo behavior. You may want to contact Maximo support by opening a PMR...